# Sending an activerecord object through Ajax to a controller action

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax

```
Rails 5.2
```

What I would like to do is, from a view, pass an Ajax request to a controller, with an activerecord object. I am doing the following;

I have an activerecord object: @book, with the following attributes:

```
@book.author
@book.title
@book.publisher
```

I have a view that includes a couple of frames, that displays several books, and when one of the books is selected, I would like to update the second frame with that book's information. In that view, I have the following Ajax code:

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    headers: {
        'X-CSRF-Token': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
    }
});
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/books/5/",
    data: JSON.stringify({
        "book": <%= raw @book %>
    }),
    datavalue: 'html',
    dataType: 'json',
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    remote: true
});
```

The books controller, is receiving it, but when I examine params[:user] (by outputing it to the console, from the controller method), I see that it's the following string:

```
{"author"=>"Joe Smith", "title"=>"My Book", "publisher"=>"Local Press"}
```

I am trying to turn this into an Hash, or an object, like this:

```
book = JSON.parse(params[:book])
```

Or:

```
book = JSON.parse(book, object_class: OpenStruct)
```

But book is coming back as nil. Any ideas?

Comment: What are you actually trying to do? By convention, you would normally to a `POST` to `/books` to create a new `Book`. What, in your example, is `5`? The `id` of a `Book`? Normally, you would do a `PATCH` or  `PUT` to `/books/5` to update the `Book` with the `id` of `5`. This all looks a little curious.

Comment: The `params` is of type `ActionController::Parameters`. It behaves like `Hash` but if you want `Hash` object, just do `params[:book].to_h` and it will return hash.

Comment: 5 is the book id, and I am trying to display it in the second panel. I already have the @book object

Comment: Classic X&Y problem. While you can marshal ruby objects its a big security issue. Just send JSON containing the attributes you want to allow. Better yet rephrase the question so that you're asking about the problem you are actually trying to solve - not your attempted solution.

Comment: I will attempt to rephrase the question. I am just trying to show my work so far, as opposed to saying: please solve this for me

Comment: btw, @peaksandvalleys, side issue here, since others have helped with your main question... you should not need to add the csrf token, jquery-rails will do this for you by intercepting the ajax request. Just use jquery-rails instead of jquery.